# Why do Google Map API questions tend to get downvoted so often?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, voting

Today, [I posted a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23477460/labels-on-google-maps) regarding a [Google Map API](https://developers.google.com/maps/) on Stack Overflow.  A few minutes after I posted my question, I got 2 downvotes.  The 2 downvotes came before any comments.

I felt that my question was totally valid.  Something I could not find in the documentation that I felt I could get help on.

I ended up getting an answer to my question, and then deleting it to avoid the reputation decrease.

Just now, I thought to filter by [that tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps) and see the type of voting on it, and the BIG SURPRISE is: there are more downvoted questions than there are upvoted ones.  This tells me that there is someone that just keeps downvoting questions for no reason.

I really like Stack Overflow, but now I feel that it is no place for learning.  Am I right? Or am I taking this the wrong way?

Comment: This is extremely difficult to comment upon without seeing your question. Can you provide a link to it at least for the 10k+ users?

Comment: I think it's [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23477460/labels-on-google-maps)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23477460/labels-on-google-maps undeleted it for now

Comment: But dont just look at my question.  Look at the whole picture http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps

Comment: I wouldn't have downvoted yours; it's asking "how to do x" but it's not easily Google-able, it's a clear question, and you have done previous research. Most of the other downvoted questions on the first page are, IMO, bona fide low quality questions, asking "how to do x" with no context at all, or requesting debugging help with too little info

Comment: Instead of a link to what you tried but didn't workout I would have posted the code...

Comment: @Cupcake is it a bait-title?  What should be the guideline for the title? I do appreciate your response...

Comment: @rene I wasn't asking for code.  I was asking for guidance.  I could not find code to get me to my solution.  The answer that worked was a simple link.

Comment: @malkassem That is not the point. [*We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You say in your question that a particular solution doesn't work for you. If you show that code other members understand that you're not a *givemethecode* type of OP. And that might be the reason you attract downvotes.

Comment: @rene I see what you mean, but what point is there showing a piece of code that is entirely unrelated to the OP's problem?

Comment: @Pekka웃 I don't think I say that. The question is about a marker on a map. The OP states he did that with the image. Show that! Then ask: How do I get the text next to the custom image marker?

Comment: @malkassem I fixed your title for you, now it's more descriptive and more clearly explains the content of this question (though you're actually asking several slightly different questions in this question `:P`). With a little hesitance, I am now removing my downvote...this time `:P`

Comment: Thank you all for the input and answering my questions...  I love Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow and I always have the confidence that I will find an answer to my questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I were to guess, I'd say that there is a large proportion of users who ask questions about how to get a Google Map to work, but who lack the necessary background in programming to properly understand the answers or to look up the answers themselves in the documentation.

It's a well-known fact that certain tags have a reputation for low-quality posts.  The experts in some of those tags may have developed itchy trigger fingers.  In any case, I don't see anything overtly wrong with the question you asked.

[I've posted an answer to your Google Maps question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23481853/456814), extending [the comment below the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23477460/how-to-place-textual-labels-directly-on-a-google-map#comment35996917_23477460) [that you've stated answers your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23477460/how-to-place-textual-labels-directly-on-a-google-map#comment35997233_23477460).

Comment: Ugh, copy/pasting an existing resource is not the SO way.  Are you going to maintain it?

Comment: @HansPassant: Nope.  The alternative is to provide the link only and let *them* maintain it.  Why would it be any different if I provided my own writing?  I'd still have to maintain that, wouldn't I?

Comment: Of course you'd maintain your *own* unique answer to a question.  Nobody else will.  Surely you see the difference?