# Why is almost every Go question downvoted?

Tags: discussion, questions, question-quality

What is the difference between [Go](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_%28programming_language%29) developers and other developers that makes so many Go-tagged questions to be downvoted?

Are Go-tagged questions less on topic, or do the Go language moderators have a stricter personality?

How is it possible that in general for a long time, more Go question are downvoted in relative to another questions?

### Go:

[image]

### JavaScript

[image]

Comment: Different crowds with different conceptions of quality may be.

Comment: It makes me move to https://gophers.slack.com. I don't want to use this site for asking Go questions.

Comment: I don't know about your questions but a few of the questions in your screenshot were missing some information at some point, according to the comments left on them.

Comment: You can make a query here: data.stackexchange.com. I'm sure you will see that it is an repeated pattern

Comment: By the way, for JavaScript: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338923/new-lows-in-js-tag-quality

Comment: Seems to me the proportion of positive/negative questions is relational to how popular a language actually is.  19,337 questions in Go vs 1,273,665 questions in JavaScript, the negatives are going to be much easier to spot.

Comment: @Claies: That ought to mean more downvoted questions in JavaScript. The opposite is shown to be the case here. I find it hard to believe the vast majority of the 1.27 million JS questions are remotely close to the sort of quality Stack Overflow takes pride in.

Comment: @BoltClock The script kiddies are nagging at our walls. The PHP zombies are walking in from the other side :P

Comment: I don't believe. My question here, in the meta about Go is  down voted? I'm sure that there is a hidden "Go bot" that automatically `question.match(/Go/).downVote()`?

Comment: I may have not expressed myself clearly enough;  when you view the Go category, the smaller number of overall questions asked means that the newest 15 questions go back 12 hours or more, where the newest 15 JavaScript questions no more than an hour.  When you just scan the newest questions page for each tag, you're much more likely to see multiple questions with DownVotes when the questions have been around for 12 times as long.  The question here *suggests* that there might be a pattern, but only shows a flawed comparison.

Comment: @Claies: Ahhh, I get it now.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that might be a pattern. I checked it for a long time. The screenshots are only for illustration.

Comment: @Aminadav I didn't downvote, I just added my opinion on the matter, but I suspect that this question is downvoted based on the presentation; specifically things like the over-generalization "almost every Go question" in the title, and the lack of concrete evidence other than a single set of screenshots that show a single moment in time, not demonstrating the trend that you mention here.

Comment: A very similar question: [*Why do Google Map API questions tend to get downvoted so often?*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253662/2751851)

Comment: A related discussion: [*Is there a downvote rate per tag statistic?*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/337143/2751851)

Comment: Hm, nobody mentioned that voting on meta is different? Well [voting on meta is different](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: If you want to see what a sh*tshow really looks like, go check out [tag:seo]

Comment: I do have to say I've also noticed that a more go questions are down voted than any other tag I look at

Answer (score 40, accepted):

A couple of possibilities come to mind.

1. There is no real correlation between tags and votes; you're just seeing one here because [that's what the human brain does](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareidolia).
2. Smaller tags like Go have fewer users and therefore fewer votes being cast overall, thus altering the proportion of upvotes and downvotes, and changing the total scores.

   Also, fewer questions means that people who follow the tag are actually able to monitor all of the questions, and therefore vote thoroughly on each one of them. Therefore, the vote totals more accurately express the opinions of the community as a whole, rather than the small subset of users who just so happened to see a particular JavaScript question fly by.
3. High-level languages/technologies like JavaScript are much more "general interest" and attract people of varying skill sets. A large proportion of the people looking at JavaScript questions are not expert programmers and will naturally find different types of things useful. They're also probably more likely to upvote and less likely to downvote.

   On the other hand, Go is a lower level language (following as it does in the tradition of C and Algol) and this tag tends to be monitored by experts with very different views on quality and what is useful. Obviously not everyone that is interested in Go is an expert in Go, but they're almost certainly still experienced programmers, very likely with a background in C or other languages.

   Also, along these same lines of reasoning, Go isn't the language of choice (as far as I'm aware) in any computer-science programs, whether at elementary, undergraduate, or community/continuing education levels. It is primarily a production language, used by real programmers working out there in the industry, who have high quality standards and a low tolerance for useless questions. You still have newbies, of course, and like any Q&A site, they're primarily the ones asking questions, but that doesn't mean that they are the ones who primarily cast votes.

Comment: *experts with very different views on quality and what is useful* → very good point, I would add "useful to **them**". I do not believe SO is a place where you are supposed to wall off people whose questions are not useful to you (the member of a community). They obviously have another point of view - so I will refrain from asking questions about Go there, so that the Go community is free from introduction questions and remains a bro club. I honestly think thi is not what SO was intended to be.

Comment: @WoJ I agree completely that people should not downvote something that was not useful to themselves if they judge that it would likely be useful to others. That said, even if we're talking about what Q&As are useful to novices, experts and novices are quite likely to have different judgements about that, too. Either because experts can consider with the benefit of hindsight what was useful to them back when they were a novice, or because experts have forgotten what it is like to be a novice. (Probably a bit of both.)

Comment: My experience has been that asking good questions is a specialized skill. Novices lack the insight (almost by definition) to ask the question clearly and coherently; experts are distant enough that they might not ask a question that accurately reflects the cause of confusion. More importantly, though, experts have a hard time getting themselves to put in the effort, in the first place, to ask an "easy" question for which they already know the answer. (Not to mention, domain knowledge != communication skill.) I guess it feels self-denigrating or something? That seems relatable.

Answer (score 15):

**This is probably an illusion, at least as things stand at the moment.**

I [wrote a SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1766176?tag=go) to select questions with a specific tag, bin them as upvoted (net score > 0), zero (net score 0) or downvoted (net score < 0), and show counts for each bin. (credit [to Martin](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384888/173477) for help with doing this efficiently.)

For the [go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go) tag, I get 24097 upvoted, 25619 downvoted, 19880 zero-score questions: 36.8% downvoted.

Compare to, for example, [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python): 531821 upvoted, 678061 downvoted, 934212 zero-score questions - 31.6% downvoted.

Or [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c): 112084 upvoted, 134615 downvoted, 150530 zero-score - 33.9% downvoted.

Numbers subject to change over time, of course - this is just what I got trying the queries just now.

Anyway, the numbers for the Go tag don't seem way out of line. Yes, the percentage of questions that get downvoted is a little higher. *But if we ignore the zero-score questions and just compare upvoted:downvoted, the situation reverses*: now the Go community looks more positive than others. And it certainly appears that Go questions are much less likely to be ignored completely.

Maybe that's a community-size effect. Let's try [perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl) - another language with a comparable number of total questions. We get... 25273 upvoted, 23139 downvoted, 19279 zero. 34.2% downvoted. Even closer, and we do see the "fewer zero-score questions" effect as well.

FWIW, I recall hearing that Haskell questions have a reputation for relatively high quality as judged by the community. This is borne out in the current analysis: I get 29019 upvoted, 12486 downvoted, 9190 zero-score questions.