# What is the expected content of questions in the Go community?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions, community

Whenever I post a question in the Go community it gets downvoted. I also post other questions in different groups/topics and I get a bit of everything: sometimes a downvote, sometimes an upvote - all this for now 13 or so years.

Go is the only place that seems to be actively hostile to newcomers to the language. While I do not support this, I can understand that it wants to be kept as a repository of advanced questions only.

In this case, why not state it upfront to avoid wasting everyone's time afterward?

To add to this - the answers to the questions are usually very good and to the point, so there is apparently value for questions from beginners.

Is the Go community in SO expecting only advanced questions and actively pushing back simpler ones?

Note that I am not talking about *bad* questions (not even mine - I saw a lot of good beginner questions downvoted a lot), but about *beginner* ones.

Comment: The Go community, as any other "tag community", is not monolithic. What the "community" accepts and what it doesn't it's simply an artifact of who sees what questions when. The rules for Go or for any other language are the same.

Comment: _"I am posting this question here with the hope that someone will redirect me to a better place."_. Then probably this is the wrong place to ask about this. If you want a site recommendation for a site outside the SE network, it's simply not topical for meta.

Comment: @yivi: no, I meant within SE of course. I did not see any group of "moderators for the Go tag" or something like that to ask them the question directly.

Comment: @yivi: I know it is not monolithic, but I find it weird that there is so much downvote. I like Go, I like SO so after some initial WTFs when I started to learn Go I am genuinely interested. But apparently, I am alone with this weird interest (-4 on this question so far) so I give up :)

Comment: There is no site devoted to Go exclusively. You can check the [list](https://stackexchange.com/sites).

Comment: @yivi I know that there is no site for Go - I was looking for "a place" where I could ask my question: a chat, a community, a list of moderators, whatever (within SE)

Comment: I think you meant Meta.SO, which is where you asked this question. This is the right place. There is no other place to discuss the content of Stack Overflow.

Comment: As for the rules of Go vs other tags: the rules are the same. Every question is expected to be of the highest quality and with lasting value for future readers. If a question is going to help only a single person then it's likely to get downvoted.

Comment: Relevant: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339273/why-is-almost-every-go-question-downvoted

Comment: And since chat was mentioned... there _is_ a [Go chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240667/go) here with fairly recent activity, although I do not know what kind of users frequent it nor whether you will find active 
 [tag:go] curators there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every question is expected to be of the highest quality and with lasting value for future readers regardless of the tag.

From [Stack Overflow tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour):

> **Stack Overflow** is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. It's built and run *by you* as part of the [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/) network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed, high-quality answers to every question about programming.