# Why do I always get downvotes on Go questions?

Tags: discussion, support, post-ban

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong on my questions in [Go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_%28programming_language%29) as I always get downvotes.

Do you think something can be improved in these questions? Can I do something else to avoid being banned?

*[Deleting endpoint in Go is not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73249646/delete-endpoint-in-golang-not-working-as-expected/)*

*[Improving GET request using the default Go HTTP client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73232160/improving-get-request-with-net-http-packet-in-go)*

I always try to search the site first, research documentation, but for these two questions I'm banned...

Comment: You are not banned for these two questions. You have asked a total of 45 questions.

Comment: Most importantly, the votes are on the post. Do not take them personally.

Comment: Improving get request with net/http packet: You ask how to improve a method, but don't specify the goal of the improvement. Better readability? Faster? Less memory consumption? The other question is based on a problem somewhere unrelated to your code, so also not a great question.

Comment: Relevant: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339273/why-is-almost-every-go-question-downvoted and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404775/rampant-downvoting (deleted)

Comment: *"Why do I always get downvotes on Golang questions?"* - An interesting observation that, it does seem that way if you look at your user account. But it isn't strictly Go... it just happens to be the one programming language tag you ask questions under. The same could have happened if it were Java, C# or Python. It is far from ideal, but there is a big difference in how strictly by the books questions are judged based on what tag it is under. It might also just be that you are better at asking Kubernetes questions.

Comment: As in one of the duplicate targets, also [observed / perceived nearly six years ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339273/), in 2016.

Answer (score 14):

I closed both questions.

[Delete endpoint in golang not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73249646/delete-endpoint-in-golang-not-working-as-expected/73250074#73250074)

This question seems to have just been a typo. It doesn't look useful to others unless you explain what the mistake in the URL was. Even then, the question would probably be misleading and not very useful, hence the downvotes.

[Improving get request with net/http packet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73232160/improving-get-request-with-net-http-packet-in-go)

This question needs to be narrowed down. What improvement are you looking for? If the code works and you are only looking for code review, then it should have been asked on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I can have it into account next time but I won’t be able to ask any other questions as I’m banned.

Comment: @XT Then you need to work on improving your remaining questions. The ban is telling you that your current contributions aren't very useful and you should first focus on improving what you already posted before posting anything new.

Comment: I’ll try to improve my previous questions just clarifying things better or adding more extra info. Those questions are gonna be reviewed from moderators, right?

Comment: No. Moderators do not usually review questions.

Comment: “… I won’t be able to ask any other questions …” - Probably should have considered the feedback on your past questions, and specifically, when you were warned about your question asking status before submitting your last question.  Since your pattern of poorly received questions, resulted in a question ban, be sure you take the opportunity to ask a higher quality question in 6 months.  Questions bans are never a result of a handful of questions.  This assumes you haven’t asked 45 questions and received 0 upvotes. 29/45 questions have not been deleted, 14 deleted, that’s not a good ratio.

Answer (score 9):

Your titles are not very informative - since SO primarily intends to be useful for other people with the same issue, a title like 'Delete endpoint in golang not working as expected' is really not very helpful, since nobody else knows what 'as expected' is meant to be. For some users, that would be grounds for a downvote as it renders the question 'not useful'.

Try and focus on titles which concisely but specifically explain your problem.