# What is wrong with my 1st question on SO?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

[Visual Studio 2022 missing project templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76937886/visual-studio-2022-missing-project-templates)

This was downvoted within the first few minutes. I can't understand why it's supposedly a "bad" question?

*What did I miss or do wrong?*

- Informative title
- Clear description of problem and anticipated solution
- Included troubleshooting steps and other things I've tried
- Appropriate tagging (yes the Q was related to Visual Studio itself, not merely programming with VS)

This anonymous downvoting for no apparent reason was one of the many reasons I gave up on SO many years ago.

Comment: Of all the things you tried / found, did you also tried this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71665531 ? I have to ask because your question only states *I have followed various posted solutions* but you didn't link to any of those solutions so I'm now forced to re-do your research. That might indicate that your question is lacking information to be useful for future visitors. And as users here tend to vote on usefulness it might explain the two downvotes.

Comment: We're happy to have you back. Now let's try to work out together with the meta crowd here what needs to be done to make that specific question a valuable addition to our human curated repository of knowledge for future visitors that face the same problem.

Comment: There has probably been a few more comments in the main question which have been removed. The heat detector spotted a problematic comment there too. Maybe you also lashed out, which only works against the goal of receiving an answer. If you are not patient with your peers, why do you expect volunteers to be patient with you?

Comment: I must admit, I find the title a bit disingenuous; it states that it's your "first" question but you clearly admit that this isnt your *first* account and that nor is this your first rodeo. I *hope* you didn't create a new account to avoid  a question ban; such actions often result in your new account being destroyed, as attempting to avoid the ban is against the rules.

Comment: @rene that's where I, independently, ended up when I tried putting `visual studio community missing templates` [into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=visual+studio+community+missing+templates). Literally the first two results were that question and OP's question

Answer (score 11):

### The question itself

Aside from the possibility of being a duplicate, I see nothing wrong - which is why I'm offering an answer here at all instead of just continuing the comment section. Some people dislike IDE questions and think the site made a mistake by choosing to include them as on topic. I've been one of those, but historically I haven't really given my objection the consideration it deserves. (I think the main problem is really that allowing questions about IDEs helps attract clueless people who *don't seem to conceptually distinguish between the IDE and the language they're using* - but that clearly doesn't apply here.)

I only downvote questions that I also think should be closed, and I accept that IDE questions are on topic, so I mostly just ignore them - just as I would with questions about programming languages I don't use or know about. I'm only involved now because I read Meta and check on all the specific questions that get asked about.

### The meta stuff

> I can't understand why it's supposedly a "bad" question?

This is the part where I get a bit confused. I *would* just refer you to [the network-wide canonical](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325416) about downvotes and why we value their anonymity, and talk about the fact that we can't tell you who downvoted or [what their reasoning was](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215379).

But then we get to this part...

> This anonymous downvoting for no apparent reason was one of the many reasons I gave up on SO many years ago.

and I feel the need to try to explain why your reception *here, on Meta* - [where we are much more free to speak our minds](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) has been so negative. (I'm going to assume that you had an account many years ago, had no disciplinary issues, deleted the account normally, then today you're coming back and recalling an unpleasant memory - i.e., that you *aren't* admitting to ban evasion or anything like that).

In short, we don't like ranting, and many of us consider that this attitude of yours is completely unjustified, despite how common it is.

The thing about these complaints about "the anonymous downvoting for no apparent reason" on Stack Overflow, when objectively it's *nowhere near* at the level of other websites that offer user-generated content plus downvotes.

The data speaks for itself.

The voting culture of the site is [overwhelmingly positive](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1776835). Among users who have reached the downvote privilege threshold, 88% of votes are up. I've done [more sophisticated analyses](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1766118/) before, but people don't seem to understand the results. The point in this one is that only extremely active voters - the people who get involved in trying to curate the site and clean up the mess that's left behind by people who treat it like a discussion forum - actually cast any significant fraction of downvotes; people with fewer than 2000 or so total votes cast more than 90% of them upward.

The "anonymous feedback" that we collect (from people who click on the arrows without being logged in, or when they don't have the necessary privileges) is much more negative, by the way. When people are arriving at questions from a search and evaluating whether the question was helpful, they're a *lot* more critical than when they're actively trying to be part of a community. Go figure.

The highest-voted content on the site reaches 5-digit net scores; there are barely any examples of anything ever reaching -100. Less than half of users with the downvote privilege have **ever** cast a downvote; 60% of users with the upvote privilege (a much larger pool) have cast at least one upvote.

More specifically, [visual-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio) questions end up [with net upvotes more often than net downvotes](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1767177), and about 26.8% downvoted, which is [in line with other tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/425398).

I could go on.

Meanwhile, consider how the meta discussion plays out on other sites. Nobody ever complains about the fact that downvoting on Reddit is anonymous. (Instead, they complain about all the fake votes the system is adding automatically, ostensibly to help defeat third-party voting bots by making it harder for them to determine if their vote went through.) They don't complain that people do it for no reason; they complain about it happening for ideological reasons (which *shouldn't* be an issue on Stack Overflow, but we're still human after all).

There's also the part where a downvote on Reddit completely cancels out the "karma" you get from an upvote. So even people who are totally focused on imaginary internet points, have five times as much reason to complain there as they do here (where reputation is increased by 10 for an upvote and decreased by only 2 for a downvote - something I personally would change). In fact, it's even starker than that, as Reddit will track negative karma for users all the way down to -100.

On YouTube, not only did people not complain about the ability to dislike videos anonymously, they *actively complained about that information being hidden* - and even accused that this was being done to silence criticism.

So, why do people rant about this on Stack Overflow?

Comment: *why do people rant about this on Stack Overflow?* ... because we can. And when we do one poor soul is distracted for at least 15 minutes writing an extensive meta answer preventing  them from casting downvotes on the main site ... win-win?

Comment: @rene I've largely given up on site curation, and soon I'll probably give up on Meta participation too. Catch me at Codidact, btw.

Comment: Must admit, downvotes on Reddit are pretty brutal. Especially because people like to dogpile. You have to be really careful about which subreddits you participate in, because you might end up having a very bad day if you get targeted by the cancellation squad. Then again, upvotes can be pretty epic. I once received thousands of points of karma for posting merely 6 words that apparently resonated with a lot of people.